# How to write my own virtual machine like VirtualBox?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualization

I would like to write virtual machine. Ideally I want to write program, which will be run(emulate) windows 7(from .iso) and show it in window on Windows 7 parent. But I can't understand how to do it. I understand how to emulate cpu, for example, just write wrapper(interface) which will be provide real cpu resources(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43176/How-to-create-your-own-virtual-machine), but what next? how to run OS, which will be use this abstraction interface of cpu. Bios starts OS, should I emulate bios? how to do it? From what should I start? Please, describe me the basic steps to implement my task. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: As I'm sure will be pointed out to you shortly -- this question is NOT appropriate for Stackoverflow. If you are just looking for a pointer for where to start your research, I recommend http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page.

Comment: if you're unable to read a site's FAQ before posting an inappropriate question, then you'll also likely be completely unable to even get close to writing such a sophisticated piece of software. apparently, you need to learn way more about the fundamentals of operating systems and software development in general before even attempting to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure years and years of work go into these type of programs. However, to get a taste of emulating CPU and coding it yourself, have a look at [nand2tetris](http://www.nand2tetris.org).
It starts by looking at the logic and arithmetic first, slowly working your way towards program control, high-level language and making a operating system.

Hope this helps!

(BTW it provides all materials and software for free!)